# How to use curl instead of fopen to send the data to url

Tags: php, curl, fopen

I am integrating Payment gateway. For that one if I use the **fopen** the data returns correctly. I need to use curl instead of **fopen**. But I am unable to get the result with **curl**.

**fopen code is like this**

```
$url = "https://test.ctpe.net/frontend/GenerateToken";
$data = "SECURITY.SENDER=xxxxxx" .
   "&TRANSACTION.CHANNEL=xxx" .
   "&TRANSACTION.MODE=xxxx_TEST" .
   "&USER.LOGIN=xxxx" .
   "&USER.PWD=xxxx" .
   "&PAYMENT.TYPE=xxx" .
   "&PRESENTATION.AMOUNT=xxxx" .
   "&PRESENTATION.CURRENCY=xxxx" .
    "&IDENTIFICATION.TRANSACTIONID=xxxxx" ;
$params = array('http' => array(
         'method' => 'POST',
         'content' => $data
       ));
$ctx = stream_context_create($params);
$fp = @fopen($url, 'rb', false, $ctx);
if (!$fp) {
  throw new Exception("Problem with $url, $php_errormsg");
}
$response = @stream_get_contents($fp);
if ($response === false) {
  throw new Exception("Problem reading data from $url, $php_errormsg");
}
```

Here **Curl Code**

```
$ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);       
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json','Content-Type: application/json'));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$params);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, FALSE);
         $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
```

This will returns **Format Error data**. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're setting `Content-Type: application/json` but the data is _not_ JSON encoded. Does the server check that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use $data with CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS option instead of $params.

```
Your current code: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$params);
It should be: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);
```

Comment: Please remove curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json','Content-Type: application/json')); and try again.